# How do I emit the SHA1 of a git branch using MSBuild

Tags: git, syntax, msbuild, escaping

The following git command...

```
git show -s --pretty=format:%T master
```

...will emit the SHA1 of the current head of master.

However the following MSBuild task only produces a literal 'T'

```
<Exec Command="git show -s --pretty=format:%T master" />
```

**What do I need to change, to emit the genuine SHA1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently the trick is to double escape the % sign.

ie

```
<Exec Command="git show -s --pretty=format:%25%25T master" />
```

I'm not really sure why this works though, so I'd appreciate comments on why this might be.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I thought we only needed one %25 to represent a % sign!  This fixed it!  Thank you thank you thank you!